# PuTTY fatal Error - Connection Refused

Tags: putty

I am connecting to remote server via SFTP using PuTTY.

I am able to connect it from my local Windows 7 machine. However, when I connect it from Windows Server 2012 R2, it gives me following error -

**PuTTY Fatal Error**

**"Network Error: Connection Refused"**

[image]

I am not sure whether it is related to SSH service/telnet service. Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you already try connecting to your machine using FileZilla?

Answer (score 2):

**Connection Refused** means that you are not allowed to connect in that manner to the target device. Practically, either the **port is not allowed**/correct, the connection **type** (telnet, SSH, SFTP, etc) or the **IP** you want to connect from (may be not allowed in the device's configuration).

Check the target device and make sure it allows the type of connectivity you require.

Answer (score 1):

It's rare though on occasion documentation actually contains the answers:

https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/getting-started-guide/accessing-your-account/using-ssh-secure-shell#Windows-operating-systems

> A2 does not use the default SSH port 22. Please SSH to port 7822.

Check to see if your web host has changed the port number or if you've accidentally changed the port number in the program.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Please check in network setting in windows [image]

Make changes in properties.According.